# Content going under footer in Google Chrome and not FF

Tags: sticky-footer

If you take a look at the site in Firefox, everything will appear normal and the footer will stick to the bottom. However in Google Chrome, the footer sticks to the bottom, but the content goes under it if the window is not large enough.

I've spent the last three hours trying to fix it, I would really appreciate it if anybody knows the solution.

Here is the site: http://rawonline.com.au/clarkwindows/service.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `#footerWrap` CSS to this:

```
#footerWrap {
    height: 277px;
    background: url(images/footerbg.png) left 277px repeat-x; /* AMEND THIS */
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 277px; /* ADD THIS */
}
```

****EDIT****

Ok, in that case, what you need to do is
Move your `<div class="push">` inside the `<div id="wrapper">`
and change .push to:

```
.push {
    height: 277px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Also, add `position: relative` to `wrapper` and `footerWrap`

Comment: Thanks for you reply, unfortunately it fixes it overlapping, but it also creates a scrollbar when the window is larger. Any ideas?